# Message encoding

Tags: ros, messages, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any documentation about how ROS serializes/encodes messages over a network? E.g. is it some binary format? XML? etc.

I don't have an install of ROS handy so I'd rather not have to set it up and run Wireshark or something. Thanks for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38469/message-encoding/) by [Neal](https://answers.ros.org/users/2810/neal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-07-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [ROS/Connection Header](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Connection%20Header) page should contain some of the information you're after.

---

Edit (I was curious as well): [How to know where the next variable begins in a serialized message?](http://answers.ros.org/question/10336/how-to-know-where-the-next-variable-begins-in-a/) seems related.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Neal](https://answers.ros.org/users/2810/neal/) on 2012-07-10**:
Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.